# How to translate Scala API DataFrame query to SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Considering such transformation in spark sql:

```
df.withWatermark("timestamp", "1 hour")
      .groupBy(window($"timestamp", "10 seconds"), $"partition")
      .count()
```

How can I write a SQL statement to achieve the same goal?
Then I can use `sparkSession.sql(sql)` to do it.